# Animate video on scroll like iPhone 6 website

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, scroll, easing

I am trying to animate a video on scroll like the [landing page for the new iPhone 6](https://www.apple.com/iphone-6/). I have the video animating on scroll, but I am trying to some how ease the the video once the mousewheel has been released. I'm not sure how I should approach this challenge. Should I be trying to use an actual easeOut function? Or should I do it some other way?

Here is a snippet of the JS I currently have. And a live example [here](http://codepen.io/ftntravis/pen/sheIE).

```
function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
  return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t * t * t + 1) + b;
};

var $win = $(window),
    $video = $('video'),
    frameRate = 29.97,
    target = 0,
    scroll = 0,
    isTicking, scrollTimeout, delta, target;

var ScrollVideo = function() {

    this.scrollY = 0;

    $win.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', this.onScroll.bind(this)); 
};

ScrollVideo.prototype = {

    /**
     * Callback for our scroll event
     * keeps track of the last scroll value
     */
    onScroll: function(event) {

        var e = event.originalEvent ? event.originalEvent : event; // get original event if available

        target += (e.wheelDelta > 0) ? -70 : 70;
        if (target < 0) target = 0;

        delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));

        this.requestScrollTick();
    },

    /**
     * Calls rAF if it hasn't already
     * been done
     */
    requestScrollTick: function() {

        if( !isTicking ) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(this.scrollHandler);
        }
        isTicking = true;
    },

    /**
     * Animate stuff on scroll
     */
    scrollHandler: function() {

        scroll += (target - scroll) * 0.1;

      console.log(scroll);

        if(delta < 0) {
            $video[0].currentTime += (1 / frameRate);
        }
        else {
            $video[0].currentTime -= (1 / frameRate);
        }

        // stop ticking
        isTicking = false;
    }
};

var scrollVideo = new ScrollVideo();
```

I'd love to be able to tackle this, any help/direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Creating your own easyOut would be my approach as well. I think you'd need to pass the delta of the previous event call and create your own calls after the last event fired (and a new one hasnt fired for x milliseconds for example) and just easyOut that delta until you reach the desired "stop" value.